# Loopback4 - How to create JWT auth with roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, loopbackjs

Well the title pretty much sums it up. I'm trying to add authentication to my app, but i'm hitting a LOT of errors.

I'm pretty new to nodejs and especially Loopback4 and i get stuck quite a lot.

For testing purposes i tried implementing `@loopback/authentication` but i'm encountering an error such as `The key controller.current.ctor was not bound to any value.` 
I followed the tutorial to the letter and quadruple checked my code to make sure everything is fine. Where others say it works, for me it doesnt.

Either way, that was just as a test implementation. I'm trying to find a way to implement a better authentication which should look for user roles as well.

Lets say i want to create a blog api with loopback and i needs POSTS to be accessed by this -> Users who are authors. Users who have the role `admin, moderator, etc` and to restrict access to unauthenticated users.

LB4 documentation is pretty small and since i'm new to this i'm literally stuck. Any help, snippets, etc would be highly appreciated!

P.S: I'm using `MySQL` as my DB.